# Associative & Index Array

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, associative-array

I created an PHP array with `mysql_fetch_array` from my SQL database.
I retrieved it to JavaScript with ajax and jQuery.

My problem is that JavaScript created two array, one simple and one associative, instead of PHP where both are in one.

When I update a cell by accessing it with index value `myArray[0]`, the associative value of the same cell `myArray['col1']` is not updated.

Is there a way to get the key from a stand alone cell from index value so I can update both arrays at the same time?

**Update:**

Here is the PHP code wo generate the array (XY).

```
 $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM details_moteurs ORDER BY m_no_inventaire ASC")
    $i=0;
    while ($infosMoteurs = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
        $arrayMoteur[$i] = $infosMoteurs;
        $i++;
    }
```

The firt column of my table **details_moteurs** is **m_id**.

```
// javascript code
Alert($arrayMoteur[0][0]) // give '1524'
Alert($arrayMoteur[0]['m_id']) // give me  '1524'
```

But if i want to update a cell of my bi-dimensional array with:

```
$arrayMoteur[0][0] = 'xyz';  
alert($arrayMoteur[0]['m_id']) // give me '1524'
```

And same:

```
   $arrayMoteur[0]['m_id'] = 'xyz';  
   alert($arrayMoteur[0][0]) // give me '1524'
```

And my problem is that I used a loop:

```
 for(x = 0;x < arraySize;x++){
       for(y = 0;y < lineSize;x++){
            if(something){
                 $arrayMoteur[x][y] = 'xyz';
            }
        }
    }
```

================================================================

Okay i fixed it.

I replaced mysql_fetch_array by mysql_fetch_assoc to get only one array, and I corrected my loops with:

```
for(var x in array)
       for(var y in array[x]){
            if(something){
                 $arrayMoteur[x][y] = 'xyz';
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: How did Javascript "create" 2 arrays? I am not sure what you mean by "in PHP both are in one"

Comment: Maybe you should show us the PHP code that generates the ajax response (and also the response body itself)…

Comment: That's what JQuery does: pure black magic ;). Show us your incantation and we will see what shazam went wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript does not create two separate arrays -- it simply creates an object where you can reference it's properties via an associative array syntax.  Try the following out in your console:

```
var test = [];
test[0] = "value0";
test["col1"] = "value1";
test["col2"] = "value2";
console.log(test.length);
```

If you run the above code, you will see that the length of the array is actually just 1.  The values for keys "col1" and "col2" are added as properties to the array object, not as entries in the array.  Assuming that all the entries that you added to your javascript array were strings (eg., all the php generated keys were strings), then you can easily loop through all the keys in order using this:

```
for (key in test) { 
    console.log( test[key] ); 
}
```

The above code in our example would print out:

```
value0
value1
value2
```

Hope this clears up what is happening to your javascript array/object.

**Update:** If you need/want the 0..n elements to match your properties you could execute this after creating your initial javascript object with the associative references:

```
var test = [];
test["col1"] = "value1";
test["col2"] = "value2";

var i = 0;
for (key in test) { 
    test[i] = test[key];
    i++; 
}
```

In our example above, you would actually end up with 4 keys.  Running this code:

```
for (key in test) { 
    console.log( "[" + key + "] --> " + test[key] ); 
}
```

outputs:

```
[0] --> value1
[1] --> value2
[col1] --> value1
[col2] --> value2
```

However, you could also just pull the two associative values using the index count like this:

```
for (var j = 0; j < test.length; j++) {
    console.log( "[" + j + "] --> " + test[j] );
}
```

This would print just the 2 values like this:

```
[0] --> value1
[1] --> value2
```

Again, hope this helps!

Comment: Hello, when you build an array with mysql_fetch_array from an SQL query you can access your array either with `myArray[0]` or `myArray['sqlCol0Name']`. But if you try to update the value with `myArray[0] = 'xxx';` and you access it with `alert(myArray['sqlCol0Name']);` the old value is still there, only `alert(myArray[0]);` will return the updated value.

Comment: myArray[0] and myArray['sqlCol0Name'] are NOT the same thing in Javascript.  Javascript is NOT PHP.  Once you create the javascript object, the reference to the 0th element in the array is not the same as the reference to a property named 'sqlCol0Name'.

Comment: My problem is not to get the value, which works already but to overwrite them, see updated first post. :)